# My VS Code says it cannot find the dotnet command

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I am new to VS Code and wanted to start learning c# with it. I ran into a problem when creating a new terminal, it said it was unable to find the dotnet command, but I already have it downloaded. I am using it on Mac, how am I able to fix this?
I tried restarting VS Code but it was still the same. I also tried running `sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet`  but this didn't seem to work.